# GAM factor-smooth interactions and model selection

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model

I'm working with a dataset which is a long-term animal abundance survey collected from 11 sites, which have different average temperature(also there are some missing years for some sites). Here, the abundance [referred to as `TrapRate3` (a probability of capture ranging from 0~1) in the code] from all sites suggest a decreasing trend, which I hypothesis influenced by the increasing temperature (referred to as `PT36`). My aim is to model the temperature effect on abundance while accounting for `Site` as a random effect and make predictions to see abundance change if temperature continue increase in the future.

For clarify, here are simple plots of my dataset, `TrapRate3 vs. Year`, `PT36 (Temperature factor) vs. Year` and `TrapRate3 vs. PT36`,respectively.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Because I’m interested in the global temperature effect, so I fitted as

`TrapRate3 ~ Site + s(T) + s(T, by = Site, m = 1) + s(Year)`:

`m1<-gam(TrapRate3~Site+s(PT36, k=5,m=2,bs="tp")+s(PT36, by=Site, k=5, bs="tp",m=1)+s(Year,bs="tp",k=5), method="REML", family = binomial,weights = March,data=c2)`

`summary(m1)`

```
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
TrapRate3 ~ Site + s(PT36, k = 5, m = 2, bs = "tp") + s(PT36, 
by = Site, k = 5, bs = "tp", m = 1) + s(Year, bs = "tp", 
k = 5)

Parametric coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -4.37220    0.23710 -18.440  < 2e-16 ***
 SiteDF      -0.33215    0.68777  -0.483 0.629144    
 SiteDY       0.01839    0.26379   0.070 0.944432    
 SiteLS       0.57169    0.27442   2.083 0.037227 *  
 SiteLZ       0.85859    0.24881   3.451 0.000559 ***
 SiteSN       1.33748    0.24921   5.367 8.01e-08 ***
 SiteTZ       0.33294    0.46194   0.721 0.471073    
 SiteWA       0.82360    0.26247   3.138 0.001702 ** 
 SiteXF       1.05429    0.24690   4.270 1.95e-05 ***
 SiteYQ       1.00026    0.30197   3.312 0.000925 ***
 SiteZY       0.13089    0.29959   0.437 0.662192    
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df  Chi.sq  p-value    
 s(PT36)         1.000e+00  1.001   4.049 0.044225 *  
 s(PT36):SiteCG  1.636e+00  4.000  11.544 0.000747 ***
 s(PT36):SiteDF  5.911e-01  4.000   1.347 0.129350    
 s(PT36):SiteDY  9.294e-06  4.000   0.000 0.929926    
 s(PT36):SiteLS  1.986e+00  4.000   4.791 0.073857 .  
 s(PT36):SiteLZ  1.642e-04  4.000   0.000 0.489253    
 s(PT36):SiteSN  2.053e-04  4.000   0.000 0.897176    
 s(PT36):SiteTZ  1.964e+00  4.000  13.838 0.000445 ***
 s(PT36):SiteWA  8.051e-05  4.000   0.000 0.573009    
 s(PT36):SiteXF  3.634e-04  4.000   0.000 0.645788    
 s(PT36):SiteYQ  2.310e+00  4.000  21.165 1.47e-05 ***
 s(PT36):SiteZY  1.735e+00  4.000  10.338 0.001272 ** 
 s(Year)         3.929e+00  3.996 192.603  < 2e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 R-sq.(adj) =  0.606   Deviance explained = 64.5%
 -REML =    684  Scale est. = 1         n = 218
```

`draw(m1)`

[image]

My questions are:

1, Does this model appropriate for my issue? I could understand this kind modeling could account for the random intercept and slope, but I’m not sure for the different range of predictor (in my case, sites have a different average temperature---PT36). I mean, if site that experience colder temperatures on average also have a lower abundance (eg. site DF), then the model will suggest a global temperature effect with a rise of abundance with the increasing temperature. However, this wrong message is given by the site character, rather than the actual temperature-abundance relationship. (Is that right?? Or I misunderstand).

2, I'm not sure the Year trends I add with a right way. Should I need include a `Year effect by Site`: `s(Year,by=Site)`or `s(Year)+s(Year,by=Site)`,which one? 
For the model, could anyone give me any advices for improvement.

3,For the result, I could understand “s(PT36):Site” indicating how the functional response of that site differs from the global smoother, but does the significance means PT36 has a significant effect on TrapRate3 for this site or has a significant different effect from global smoother?? If the global smoother is significant, could I say 'for all sites, PT36 has a significant effect on TrapRate3'?

4, I’m a little confused about `y ~ Site + s(x, by = Site)` and `y ~ s(x, by = Site) + s(Site, bs=“re”)`. Are they both for the random intercept but with different way??

5, Besides the temperature (PT36) in my case, I also have other alternate climate factors, for example different period temperature and rainfall. I want to make model selection to choose the most influencing factor. My question is could I perform this kind of model selection just depend AIC? Also, in my case, models with different climate factor give similar AIC, so I guess I’d better check the prediction performance, right??

Really appreciate for any explanation and advices.

Comment: "interested in how the abundance has changed through time across all the sites and the difference among the sites." and " to model the temperature effect on abundance through time while accounting for Site as a random effect" cannot be realize in one model.

Comment: Thanks. I might not have explained it clearly. I actually want to model the temperature effect on abundance while also taking account the difference by a site-specific term, then using the global and site-specific smoothers combine to predict abundance for individual site. Maybe I need re-edit my question.

Comment: is "predict abundance for individual site" your ultimate aim? If yes, the "individual sites" means 11 sites included in the data, or other sides not appeared in the data?

Comment: just the 11 sites included in the data

Comment: Actually also give a global function of temperature

Comment: Therefore, there is no random effect in your model based on you want applied your model to 11 sites appeared in data and have no plan to extent the model to other sites.

Comment: Did you mean using group (Site in my case) as a random effect could be used to simulate functional variation for unobserved group levels, but not possible as a fix effect? So in my case I should use 'Site' instead of 's(Site, bs="re")'. Right??

Comment: Be careful when you talk about "random effects" in context of penalized spline-based GAMs; if following advice to choose smoothness parameters by REML or ML, pretty much everything is a random effect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Q1

In words your model

```
TrapRate3 ~ Site +
  s(PT36, k = 5, m = 2, bs = "tp") + 
  s(PT36, by = Site, k = 5, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
  s(Year, bs = "tp", k = 5)
```

posits that the response can be decomposed into

- a fixed `Site` effect; each `Site` has it's own mean,
- an average smooth effect of `PT36` over all levels of `Site`,
- a separate `Site`-specific smooth effect of `PT36` which measures the deviation from the average smooth for the $j$th level of `Site`, and
- a smooth effect of sample `Year`

The site-specific "difference" smooths are really estimating an entirely separate smooth for each level of `Site`; there is no shared information here and that implies that you are focused on this specific set of sites as you model can't generalise to other `Site`s. These smooths are also centred, which is why we require something in the model to account for the potentially different mean response values for each level of `Site`.

This model isn't saying that the population smooth effect of `PT36`, $f(\mathsf{PT36})$, applies to all unmeasured sites, sensu a random slope model in classical mixed effects modelling. However, it would be your best estimate of the effect of `PT36` on the response for some unmeasured new `Site`. Whether you can use your model to predict the response at this unmeasured `Site` in another matter; you won't have an estimate for the mean response at *any* site because of the fixed effects `Site` term in the model.

One motivation for this model is that it can be more parsimonious than

```
TrapRate3 ~ Site +
  s(PT36, by = Site, k = 5, bs = "tp") +
  s(Year, bs = "tp", k = 5)
```

*if* all or most of the $f_{\mathrm{Site}}(\mathsf{PT36})$ have a very similar shape; why estimate 11 very similar smooth functions when you can estimate a single average function and 11, potentially simpler "difference" functions?

But, having said that, one of the ways of thinking about a random effect if that the effects are penalized towards some average effect; in a random intercept, the random effects are shrunk toward the overall intercept in the model, random slopes are shrunk towards the average or population "slope" in the model. Here, the estimated smooth effects for each `Site` are shrunk towards the average smooth effect but *not* with regard to the overall model intercept - the model includes fixed effect of `Site`. So, if it walks like a duck and quacks like one too...

### Q2

Which you choose will depend entirely on how you hypothesise the `Year` effect to vary between `Sites`? If all `Sites` have largely been exposed to the same environment then one might expect a single common smooth effect of `Year`, so use `+ s(year)` only. If you hypothesise that each of the 11 sites has experienced it's own, different, set of temporal events not related to Temperature, then `+ s(year, by = Site)` would be warranted. If, however, you think that each site has experienced roughly the same set of temporally-ordered events or forcing but with some `Site`-specific idiosyncrasies, then you could use the `+ s(Year) + s(Year, by = Site, m = 1)` form.

We can't answer that question for you I'm afraid.

### Q3

The outputs in the summary are analogues of the $t$ tests of the null hypothesis that $\hat{\beta}_i = 0$ for the $i$th coefficient in the model. The difference here is that the null hypothesis assumes that the estimated function $\hat{f}_{\mathrm{Site}}(\mathsf{PT36}) = 0$, i.e. is a constant function. Is the estimated function and hence are the data consistent with this assumption?

Because of the way this smooth effect is penalized — `m=1` means a first derivative penalty penalising deviation from a flat or constant function — and the way you've set this model up, there isn't anything in this model summary that you can point to that says `PT36` has a significant effect on the response for this particular site. You couldn't do this, nor might one philosophically want to do so, if you'd estimate a random slope for each site about some population effect of `PT36` in a mixed effects model.

Here you would most likely need to predict the response for each level of `Site`, whilst holding `Year` at the average `Year`, over the range of `PT36` and plot the estimated values and the classic 95% point-wise confidence interval ($\pm$ 2 $\times$ SE($\hat{y}))$ and then look to see if the response varies over the range of `PT36` and with what level of uncertainty. (Note this 95% interval has an across-the-function interpretation, not the usual 95% pointwise interpretation as it is really a Bayesian credible interval given improper priors on the smoothness parameters).

### Q4

I've already touched on this but these two specifications are different:

- `y ~ Site + s(x, by = Site)` estimates a separate mean for each level of `Site`; there's no shrinkage towards the overall model intercept in the coefficients implied by how `Site` enters the model (by default the coefficients for `Site` are parameterised into differences from the model intercept), whereas with
- `y ~ s(x, by = Site) + s(Site, bs = "re")` the `Site` specific means are shrunk towards the overall model intercept (they're shrunk towards zero but then we add on the model intercept to get each `Site`s mean).

### Q5

You could use AIC but you do have to be sure that the model is fully penalised if you are using REML. You can switch to estimating via ML if you aren't sure to do the selection and then refit the chosen model using REML to get the best estimates for the smoothness parameters.

AIC is an estimator of the leave-one-out (IIRC) MSE of the model so your selection if using it is based on prediction error.

Instead, you could embrace the world of penalties and use `select = TRUE` in your `gam()` code, which will put a separate penalty on any unpenalized term in the bases of the smooth function in the model (not the `Site` fixed effect, you'd need to do something else to penalize that, see `paraPen` argument). This extra penalty can shrink a term entirely out of the model — i.e. do model selection for you — whilst taking into account your uncertainty about whether and which covariates were related to the response; the `summary()` output will account for this extra uncertainty.

Comment: Great, you have clarified things nicely. I think I have a deeper understanding of the model. Much appreciate. There still one following question for Q3, is that means "  when average smooth is significant, means PT36 has a significant effect over all levels of Site; and when the difference smooth (̂Site()) is significantly different (from 0), we can conclude that the sites follow a different effect from the global effect?

Comment: Here because I want to demonstrate all the sites have a similar climate factor effect (slope could different but the inverse effect for some sites is not expected). Furthermore the inverse effect couldn't be explained because all the sites have experienced a similar decreasing trend and exposed to a same changing climate. Thanks.

Comment: One more question about the interpretation of difference smooth.  I could understand the flat line means similar shape with global smoother with differing only in intercept, but I'm confused why a similar trend means a reverse pattern? (e.g.,Fig.13 smooth for Mn1 in your paper"HGAM in ecology: an introduction with mgcv"). Much appreciate.

Comment: I think my data is probably a case of what's called Simpson's Paradox, which is  appears abundance goes up with temperature, but at any given site, abundance is going down with temperature. I'm going include two variables for temperature: an average temperature in a reference period and a year-to-year deviance from average.

Comment: C1: if `s(PT36)` is significant, it means that, conditional upon the other terms in the model, that the data provide evidence against the null hypothesis that the true function $\hat{f}(\mathsf{PT36})$ is a flat constant function. If a site specific smooth is significant, this means that conditional on the other terms in the model, the deviations of the smooth function from the average is not a constant function.

Comment: C2: I'm not sure you can do this. We assume the null is true when doing these frequentist tests, where data is assessed for evidence against, not for, the null. All you can do here is show that you don't need different smooths for each level of `Site` given some metric like AIC (i.e. some prediction level measure).

Comment: C3: With `Mn1`, the 0 line would be no variation from average. As the estimated curve is lower than the average at low concentrations  and higher than average at high concentrations, this is consistent with what we wrote; that the `Mn1` curve differs from the average conversely to those for `Mc1` or `Qn1` which trend in the opposite direction.

Comment: Much appreciate @Gavin, your explanation helps me a lot. I'll think about your suggestions.